# FitBit Charge 3 not connecting in new android Phone after previously synced with iPhone

Tags: bluetooth

I previously used FitBit Charge 3 on my IPhone 6S, After it was totally broken and damaged I bought a new Samsung Galaxy M30S Android Phone.

While setting up new device I can see the message tracker found, but the Connecting is not working and buffering forever.

I tried several options like turning off Bluetooth and on, reboot fitbit device and other mentioned in forum but no luck.

I contacted customer support and they say that since you already sync with iPhone first you need to unpair from iPhone which I cannot do as it is damaged.

They suggested restarting fitbit for pressing 8 seconds which also did not work.

They said sorry and could not replace the product as warranty expired.

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: Is there a Bluetooth Classic setting on the device? The bit about unpairing first is BS. Also, take a look on here https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Charge-3/bd-p/charge3 for threads of similar issues. There might be a solution within.

Comment: @spikey_richie I don't know about FitBit, but I know a device (Bluetooth card reader) which I use that can only be paired to a single device, so if it's already paired to a phone, other devices cannot pair to that device until it's unpaired.